# ERROR: argumento 'times' inválido en R

Tags: r

[Aca esta la base de datos](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1W4jo59z2VCZI860m67VWtiQtElam1Bti/view?usp=sharing)Estoy intentado hacer un analisis de coocurrencia utilizando una matrix de 320 filas x 8 columnas
A la matrix la llamo: uno y es una matriz de 0 y 1 donde ninguna fila ni columna es completamente 0.
utilizo el siguiente codigo:

```
data(uno)
cooccur.finches <- cooccur(mat=uno,
               type="spp_site",
               thresh=TRUE,
               spp_names=TRUE)
summary(cooccur.uno)
plot(cooccur.uno)
```

Y obtengo el siguinte error: ***ERROR: argumento 'times' inválido***

Comment: Tu código es el mismo de la ayuda de `coocurr()` que funciona perfectamente, la única diferencia son los datos con el que alimentas la función. Lamentablemente sin ver estos no hay mucho que se pueda decir. Como sugerencia compara `uno` con el ejemplo que viene en el paquete `finches` y analiza las diferencias.

Comment: Es exactamente igual lo que con 320 especies

Comment: Sin embargo, el ejemplo de la ayuda de `coocur()` funciona perfectamente, y en tu caso usando los datos `uno` con el mismo código, pareciera que no, posiblemente los datos sean similares pero no idénticos.

Comment: Es una matirx de 0 y 1 sin ninguna fila completamento 0. Puedo hacer una uno<-matrix(nrow=320, ncol=8)  o de que otra forma puedo subir mis datos para q los veas??? gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Subi la basae de datos como un enlace externo

Answer (score 2):

Viendo los datos, lo que se puede observar con respecto a los datos de ejemplo, es la ausencia de nombres de fila para categorizar las especias, es cierto sí que hay una columna, pero el paquete esta esperando los nombres de especies como `rownames`. por lo que luego de descargar los datos, simplemente transformamos la variable `especies` en un `rowname`:

```
df <- read.csv('~/Descargas/unio.xls - Hoja1.csv')
rownames(df) <- df$especies
df$especies <- NULL
```

Ahora si, podemos probar la función:

```
library(cooccur)
cooccur.finches <- cooccur(mat=df,
                           type="spp_site",
                           thresh=TRUE,
                           spp_names=TRUE)
```

Y ahora, luego de la ejecución

```
> summary(cooccur.finches)
Call:
cooccur(mat = df, type = "spp_site", thresh = TRUE, spp_names = TRUE)

Of 50721 species pair combinations, 45036 pairs (88.79 %) were removed from the analysis because expected co-occurrence was < 1 and 5685 pairs were analyzed

Cooccurrence Summary:
       Species          Sites       Positive       Negative         Random 
         319.0            8.0           68.0           10.0         4035.0 
Unclassifiable Non-random (%) 
        1572.0            1.4 
attr(,"class")
[1] "summary.cooccur"

> plot(cooccur.finches)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: MUCHAS GRACIAS HA SIDO USTED DE MUCHA AYUDA. MIL GRACIAS

Comment: Aplicando esta solucion me he encontrado con algo que no entiendo, Estoy aplicando esto para otro conjunto de dato. La unica caracteristica es que es mucho mas grande. Pero eso no deberia ser impedimento no? Pos me sale el mismo error y lo he modificado n veces y me vuele a salir el mismo error. pueden ayudarme una vez mas?  Aca dejo el enlace de los datos https://mega.nz/file/SHZ1QKLD#iaXVlircc4Bg1wH4U8AnpzXybbdh-E8s-CJYvdANCBQ

Comment: Sigo intentando y en ocaciones obtengo ERROR: objeto 'orimat' no encontrado

Comment: Lo que puedo decirte es que la base de datos que mencionas en un comentario no tiene ningún parecido con el de tu pregunta, además el objeto `orimat` no surge del código ni de los datos. Creo que lo mejor es que en todo caso hagas una nueva pregunta. Saludos.

Comment: Ya lo hice en una pregunta aparte. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/434073/error-objeto-orimat-no-encontrado