# ERROR: objeto 'orimat' no encontrado

Tags: r

Estoy intentando hacer un análisis de coocurrencia y cuando intento plotear el gráfico obtengo  ***ERROR: objeto 'orimat' no encontrado***
Este es el código que uso:

```
library(cooccur)
data(uno)
df <- uno
rownames(df) <- df$especies
df$especies <- NULL

cooccur.finches <- cooccur(mat=df,
                           type="spp_site",
                           thresh=TRUE,
                           spp_names=TRUE)
summary(cooccur.finches)

plot(cooccur.finches)
```

La base de datos se la comparto acá: https://mega.nz/file/SHZ1QKLD#iaXVlircc4Bg1wH4U8AnpzXybbdh-E8s-CJYvdANCBQ
Gracias

Comment: La base que compartes tiene una columna llamada `ID`, este es el dato que correspondería a `df$especies` ? si es así `H120` estaría repetido o mas bien uno de los casos pareciera ser el `H122`. De cualquier forma, leyendo el excel y adaptando el código logré luego de varios minutos regenerar la gráfica y obtener el ` summary`  sin ningún mensaje de error. Lo siento pero no he podido reproducir el error.

Comment: Interntaré volver a modificar el codigo con la sugerencia que usted me hizo. Puede compartirme el summary y el graph¿?

Comment: summary: https://pastebin.com/1qwBZNuk Gráica: https://pasteboard.co/JRPE1Oo.png

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por su consejo. Es usted de muchisima ayuda. Muy agradecido